# Eclipse+Android NDK plugin takes too long to build native code on Windows+Cygwin

Tags: android

I have a lib that is derived from webRTC. I can build it from the command line. It takes an acceptable time.

I'm now trying to use the NDK plugin of eclipse to be able to debug it.
The problem is that it takes too long to build it.  It takes about 1 min per file. If there isn't a way to make it faster it would be unusable.

I'm running Eclipse on Windows. I added Cygwin for the native code.

Is this normal? Has anyone used the NDK plugin on Eclipse running on Linux? Is it so slow on Linux too? Is there something I should do to speed up the compilation?

Comment: I use windows and face the same problem. My colleagues don't have this problem, not on Linux nor on Windows. why me! :/

Answer (score 0):

I tried on Ubuntu and it is faster. I used the ADT bundle for x86_64.